# Where is the variable $LISTENTITY generated in ListViewEntries.tpl in vtiger?

Tags: vtiger

Does anyone know where the variable $LISTENTITY n ListViewEntries.tpl is generated?
I am new to this vtiger CRM, and i am in learning phase.

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be pretty late, but for $LISTENTITY, the variable is declared in the modules ListView.php file. For example, if you are looking at the Accounts module, it would be modules/Accounts/ListView.php. The code declaration is:

```
$smarty->assign("LISTENTITY", $listview_entries);
```

In fact, all smarty variables are assigned similarly. Hope this helps!